# Original UILabel for transparent view with opacity alpha 0.5

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView cell with labels, I want to make that view transparent with alpha 0.5 but not the UILabel's. I have a content view with clear background, and for the view above the content view, given with the background white with alpha value 0.5. The CollectionView is transparent but my problem is that the labels are also slightly transparent it's not much clear. please help me if anyone knows the solution.

Comment: change the layer hierarchy

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can you explain it in detail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this effect by putting your label into a view and then changing alpha component of view itself like this:

`alphaView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)`

Label shouldn't be transparent then. Ofc you need to set your label background color to clear.

Comment: my heirarchy is that collectionview - > collectionviewcell - >  alphaview - > label. What should be the background color and the alpha value for the collectionviewcell's contentview?

Comment: It should be clear color as you want it to be transparent.

Comment: Thank you !! it helped me .I wanted it in Objective c but  the concept whcick you gave helped me..

Comment: No problem. Next time mention you are using objective-C. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You should not set the alpha value of the view. If you set the alpha value of a view this value takes effect on all subviews, too. You should set the alpha value of the background color of the view.

Comment: I have set the alpha for the background color of the view

Answer (score 0):

You should not set alpha value.

Instead you can set the background colour of the uicollectionviewcell to be clear colour. In this way your collection view cell will be transparent.
Then you could give whatever color to the labels.